# Align and center images in a fixed div

Tags: html, css

i have a very simple page with a fixed footer. On this footer, i'd like to place 5 images centered with equals distances between them.

Here is my HTML/CSS : 

Footer div :

```
div.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 9%;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

And the HTML :

```
<div class="fixed">
    <img style="max-width: 80%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; max-height: 80%;" src="images/icons/icon.png">
    <img style="max-width: 80%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; max-height: 80%;" src="images/icons/icon.png">
    <img style="max-width: 80%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; max-height: 80%;" src="images/icons/icon.png">
    <img style="max-width: 80%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; max-height: 80%;" src="images/icons/icon.png">
    <img style="max-width: 80%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; max-height: 80%;" src="images/icons/icon.png">
</div>
```

Here is what i obtain :

[image: screenshot of mobile browser display]

I would like to display the red icons at the center. It should be responsive depending on the display resolution with the use of '%' values.
I thought about doing a grid in the footer. But is there an easier way to do it ?
Couldn't find anything about this on the web, hope it's not a duplicate !
Thank you in advance for any help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just add `text-align: center` on `fixed` div.

```css
div.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 9%;
  background-color: pink;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <img src="images/icons/icon.png">
  <img src="images/icons/icon.png">
  <img src="images/icons/icon.png">
  <img src="images/icons/icon.png">
  <img src="images/icons/icon.png">
</div>
```

Comment: I can't manage to align them vertically with margin-top, do you have an idea of how to do this ?

Comment: How would you like to align them?

Comment: If you look at the picture in my question, the red little icons are touching the top of the footer. How could i place them at the center of the footer, but vertically ?

Comment: If you can use fixed height on parent element you can use `line-height` https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1448/ if you can't then you can use `flexbox` https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1450/

Answer (score 4):

```css
div.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 9%;
  background-color: pink;
  text-align: center;
}
div.fixed >img{
  max-width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <img src="images/icons/icon.png">
  <img src="images/icons/icon.png">
  <img src="images/icons/icon.png">
  <img src="images/icons/icon.png">
  <img src="images/icons/icon.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to align child items vertically center and horizontally equally spaced.

```
div.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 9%;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex; //Set display to flex
  justify-content : space-around; //space equally horizontally
  align-items: center; //place at center vertically
}
```

No need to give any extra styling to child elements i.e. `<img>` in your case. Flexbox will take care of alignments and is very well supported by most of the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
div.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 9%;
    background-color: pink;
    text-align: center

}


img
{ 
  display:inline-block; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `text-align: center;` to the parent `div.fixed`